# Good Practical Resources/Workshops to get started on BPM/ADF for 11g?

Tags: resources, soa, oracle-adf, business-process-management

i'm looking for some hands on practical resources to get started with BPM/ADF and preferably SOA too, is there any site like [mkyong](http://www.mkyong.com/) or [vaannila](http://www.vaannila.com/)? I do have a background in Java and MVC Programming, but have zero experience on Oracle Suite besides the Database itself, including the Jdeveloper IDE.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for "hands-on" that will be tough. I recommend the ADF Insider Series on Oracle's site: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/adf/learnmore/adfinsider-093342.html

as well as these tutorials: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18941_01/tutorials/toc.htm

Free download here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/adf/downloads/index.html

and these sample apps: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/jdev/index-098948.html

I think this is a good book to get started: [http://www.amazon.com/Oracle-JDeveloper-11g-Handbook-Development/dp/0071602380/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1301065987&sr=8-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0071602380)

Pre-built VMs (Virtualbox) here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/community/developer-vm/index.html

BPM is a much different animal than ADF.